# Limit the Number of Characters between Double Quotes using Oracle 11g PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, substring

I need a way of applying a substring limit of 32 characters to each grouping of data inside double quotes, using Oracle 11g PL/SQL.

Basically using the following example string that is provided to me as is, as I do not have control of the way this string is constructed:

```
str := ‘"AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDDDD1","AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDD",”QWERTY”,”N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1”’;
```

I need to go through each group of values between each double quote, for example (“QWERTY”) and apply a substring of 32 to every grouping found.

So using the above string example, it’s like I need to perform the following:

```
str := ‘"substr(‘AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDDDD1’,1,32)","substr(‘AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDD’,1,32)",”substr(‘QWERTY’,1,32)”,”substr(‘N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1’,1,32)”’;
```

So in the end, my end result for str would consist of the four groupings where each grouping's length is less than or equal to 32.

Comment: What connection does it have to SQL tables?

Comment: I am not sure you can do this w/o using PL/SQL to break apart the string.  Maybe something with regex?  Not sure.

Comment: Sorry - can use PL/SQL - will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [regexp_replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions149.htm#i1305521).

```
regexp_replace(str,'"([^"]{1,32})[^"]*"','"\1"')
```

Explanation of the pattern:

```
"               --matches a double quote
([^"]{1,32})    --matches a group of 1 to 32 characters, containing anything other than double quotes.
                --surrounded by brackets, to form the first capture group.
[^"]*           --matches zero or more characters other than double quotes
"               --matches a double quote
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34036)

```
with x(str) as (
select '"AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDDDD1","AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDD","QWERTY","NoN1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1"' str
from dual
)
select str,
regexp_replace(str,'"([^"]{1,10})[^"]*"','"\1"')
from x
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34036/0)**:

```
|                                                                                                              STR | REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'"([^"]{1,10})[^"]*"','"\1"') |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| "AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDDDD1","AAAAAAA BBBBBBB CCCCCCC DDDD","QWERTY","NoN1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1N1" |  "AAAAAAA BB","AAAAAAA BB","QWERTY","NoN1N1N1N1" |
```

Comment: Just what I needed - you make it look so easy. Thanks.